# Node.js client can't see data from Express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, client, communication

I am setting up a **Client/Server** communication between my tablet and my PC. My Client cant get any data from the server, what am I doing wrong.

My PC is running a Node.js server (using Express) and my tablet runs a client written in Node.js (using Express). I can access the server via the browser and get the data, but not through the javascript code.

My **SERVER** code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('App requested a connection');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Listening on port 3000!'));

app.get("/boxes", function (req, res)
{
  //res.send(req.params[0]);
    res.send("All boxes are in the basement");

});
```

My **CLIENT** code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

console.log("Client working ...");

app.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/boxes", function (req, res)
{
    console.log("inside...");
    console.log(res);
});
```

The CLIENT should return "All boxes are in the basement" and I get this when I use a browser but it doesn't work if I run the client code. The only message I get from client is "Client working ...".

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Express is not a client..  Use something like Request ->  https://www.npmjs.com/package/request  for client requests.

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1:3000` not local to the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is a library for setting up and configuring an http server for incoming requests.  It does not make outgoing requests to other servers.  So, your client code is not a client at all.

Several problems here:

1. `127.0.0.1` refers to your local device so your client is referring to itself when it uses `127.0.0.1`.
2. In your client `app.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/boxes")` is not a request for data.  That attempts to set up an Express route for incoming requests as if you were declaring a second server.  But, it's not even done correctly because you would only use the path there.
3. For a client to make a request of some other server, you would need to use a library call that actually does http requests.  For example, you could do something like this:

Code:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
rp.get("http://ipaddressOfServer:3000/boxes").then(data => {
    // have response here
}).catch(err => {
    // error here
});
```

I chose to use the `request-promise` library, but there are multiple different ways to make an http request.  You can also use `http.get()` (lower level), `request()` (from the request library) or `axios()` from the axios library, etc...

Note, the computer your server is on (assuming it's running a desktop OS) will also have to probably turn of it's local firewall (e.g. windows firewall) or set up a specific rule to allow incoming connections on port 3000.  Without that, the incoming connection will be blocked (for security reasons).

Comment: ok, I ran the code (both client and server) on my PC and I used the "request" for now and it worked :-), thank you for the help.

Comment: ok, I ran the code (both client and server) on my PC and I used the "request" for now and it worked :-), thank you for the help. Does anybody know what is the best way to make my tablet to **see my PC across a local WiFi network**?

Comment: @user1959656 - You will have to use the local IP address of your server (not 127.0.01, but the actual IP address which can change from time to time unless you lock it down) and you will have to allow incoming connections in the desktop OS firewall.  More discussion of this should be in another question (there are already lots of other questions on this topic, you can probably learn from).